# Yii2 active form select input в одном поле

Tags: yii2, select, input, select2

Нужно если не приходит список имейлов в Select2, то давать возможность ввести самостоятельно в Input. Может в Select2 есть такое, не видел. Или другая библиотечка есть может. Подскажите. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В `Select2` есть такая возможность называется [tags](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

Пример использования:

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

Только учтите что если человек сам вводит значение свое то в обработчике нужно будет проверять пришел ключ существующего значения или новое значение.

Comment: а есть возможность ограничить до одного тега?

Comment: maximumSelectionLength: кол-во элементов